# How to use com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser?

Tags: java, jtable, jdatechooser

I'm using `com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser` to search between two dates so I've two `jDateChooser`  components.
`jDateChooser1` and `jDateChooser2` I want retrieve record after select date from second `jDateChooser2`  in `jTable`

I tried write code in `constructor` it doesn't compile cause empty
`String from = jDateChooser1.getDate();` gets `null`

> I can use `jButton` to search records but I want it  on `jDateChooser` event.

To check if it is working I tried

```
private void jDateChooser1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){                                           
    jLabel1.setText(String.valueOf(jDateChooser1.getDate()));

}
```

and

```
private void jDateChooser1MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){                                                                
    jLabel1.setText(String.valueOf(jDateChooser1.getDate()));

}
```

But it doesn't working either with
    `jDateChooser1MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)`
or
    `jDateChooser1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)`

It's working with `jButton` as I mentioned above but I don't want to use:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    jLabel1.setText(String.valueOf(jDateChooser1.getDate()));
    //Working 
}
```

So my previous title was **"How implement event for `com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser`?"**
So now my question is more clear to understand.
Thank you.

Comment: For better help post [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a listener using `dateChooser.getDateEditor().addPropertyChangeListener()`. Then listen for changes in property "date". Try below sample code.

```
import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

public class JDateChooserSample
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JLabel label = new JLabel("No date");

    JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
    dateChooser.getDateEditor().addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
      {
        if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("date"))
        {
          label.setText(String.valueOf(dateChooser.getDate()));
        }
      }
    });

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    f.getContentPane().add(dateChooser);
    f.getContentPane().add(label);
    f.setBounds(300, 200, 400, 300);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.